# Mobile app broke after an update. Am I entitled to a downgrade / refund?

Tags: software, licensing, european-union, consumer-protection

The immediate problem I have encountered is described [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/209149/access-the-call-log-to-complement-what-has-been-banned-by-policy), but I'm interested in the general concepts which apply in situations like this. What happens if a paid app stops working after an update? Google Play store provides [no way](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/10392/101383) to revert an upgrade, and according to their ToS a refund is only possible within two hours after an initial purchase:

> As a courtesy to our users, Google offers a full refund on apps and games purchased on the Play Store if the purchase is returned within 2 hours. You can only return an app or game once for a courtesy refund.

Afterwards, Play Store recommends contacting the app developer. In my case the app developer doesn't seem to provide any ToS on their [web page](https://www.callrecorder.appliqato.com/).

Does the developer have any legal grounds to refuse providing me a downgrade / refund?

Comment: Is there a TOS in the app?

Comment: @Putvi I couldn't find any. The "About" page only contains links component licenses, and there's no menu entry labelled ToS or anything close to that.

Answer (score 1):

### The provision is [unlawful](https://www.termsfeed.com/blog/return-refund-laws-eu/)

Even their [revised](https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/7659581) terms are likely unlawful because, although they backhandedly acknowledge a right to a refund for faulty product, they don’t tell you how to get it.

Further, it is misleading and deceptive and explores Google Play to fines running into the millions of Euros. No doubt this will just add to the nearly €10 billion they have been fined for anti-competitive behaviour in the last 2 years.

The product must not be faulty for a minimum of 2 years from date of purchase. If it is, the retailer(Ggoogle Play) must repair, replace or refund it - they cannot fob you off to anyone else.

Comment: They could fix the broken software though.

Comment: @Putvi  and that would be what “repair” means in the last sentence